# Setting session value in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to assign some value to a session variable via JavaScript in my aspx page.

```
 var name = e.object.text;
 <%# Session["CurrentName"] = name %>
```

Above code is giving following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'name' does not exist in the current context
```

When I googled all the post are about getting the value from session in JavaScript. But I want to set the value to a session variable in JavaScript code.

How can I assign value to session variable in JavaScript?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Accessing & Assigning the Session Variable using Javascript:**

[**See Here**](http://shekharshetemcts.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/how-to-access-session-variables-using-javascript-in-asp-net/)

**Assigning** the `ASP.NET Session` Variable using `Javascript`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function SetUserName()
{
    var userName = "Shekhar Shete";
    '<%Session["UserName"] = "' + userName + '"; %>';
     alert('<%=Session["UserName"] %>');
}
</script>
```

**Accessing** `ASP.NET Session` variable using `Javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetUserName()
    {

        var username = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>';
        alert(username );
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helped you...! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not like this.

JavaScript is client-side thus rendered after the server-side (C#). That means you can't assign session values directly through JavaScript.

One way to solve your problem would be to use AJAX to asyncronously send a request to server and change value of the session.

[Example how to do it.](http://kalpeshshirodker.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/accessing-session-from-javascript-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script runat="server">
 var name = e.object.text;
 Session["CurrentName"] = name;
</script>
```

Try this, by using `runat="server"` on script you can assign value to the `Session`